# Unable to vertically align this div

Tags: css

The snippet posted below is *very* close to my desired behavior: having a div in the center of the screen maintain its aspect ratio to the maximum size possible while being centered in its parent div. However, when the width of the screen is too small, the div is not centered, it is aligned to the top. When the width is large enough, the `margin: auto` trick works as expected and centers the div accordingly.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        html, body {
            margin: 0;
            color: white;
        }

        html, body, #root { height: 100%; }
        #top, #bottom { margin: 1em; }

        #root {
            background-color: black;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }

        #middle {
            flex: 1;
            background-color: grey;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        #box {
            margin: auto;
            aspect-ratio: 4/3;
            border: 3px solid red;
            max-width: calc(100% - 6px);
            max-height: calc(100% - 6px);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root">
        <div id="top">Top panel</div>
        <div id="middle">
            <div id="box"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="bottom">Bottom panel</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The closest solution I found to perform what I am looking for is here: https://codepen.io/wattenberger/pen/vYOOPXv. However, this works purely off view width and height. Completely ignoring the constraint of top or bottom panels like I require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add it to your `#box`.

```
position: relative;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

Comment: Wow, I tried doing this earlier, but missed the `position: relative;` part. How does that one part that fix it?

Comment: Without `position:relative`  `top`, `left`, `bottom` and `right` are not working.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the margins. In your flex container, give `align-items: center;` a try.